# Spring Boot Actuator /env endpoint response malformed when closure specified in application.groovy

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy, spring-boot-actuator

I have a standard Grails 3 application where I have added an application.groovy file to the grails-app/conf directory. This file contains a closure in the form:

```
a = {
    b = 1
}
```

When I submit a GET request to the /env endpoint provided by Spring Boot Actuator the response JSON is malformed. It contains the JSON that had successfully serialized up to the point that an object can't be serialized, and appears to have an error message serialization appended to it.

I get the following stacktrace in the console:

```
ERROR org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - JsonMappingException occurred when processing request: [GET] /env
No serializer found for class groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$1 and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.groovy]#development"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["a"]->_run_closure1["delegate"]->script14676936485701338056614["binding"]->groovy.util.ConfigBinding["callable"]->groovy.util._parse_closure6["delegate"]->groovy.util.ConfigSlurper["classLoader"]->groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader["resourceLoader"]). Stacktrace follows:
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: No serializer found for class groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$1 and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.groovy]#development"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["a"]->_run_closure1["delegate"]->script14676936485701338056614["binding"]->groovy.util.ConfigBinding["callable"]->groovy.util._parse_closure6["delegate"]->groovy.util.ConfigSlurper["classLoader"]->groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader["resourceLoader"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$1 and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.groovy]#development"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["a"]->_run_closure1["delegate"]->script14676936485701338056614["binding"]->groovy.util.ConfigBinding["callable"]->groovy.util._parse_closure6["delegate"]->groovy.util.ConfigSlurper["classLoader"]->groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader["resourceLoader"])
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_51]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$1 and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.groovy]#development"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["a"]->_run_closure1["delegate"]->script14676936485701338056614["binding"]->groovy.util.ConfigBinding["callable"]->groovy.util._parse_closure6["delegate"]->groovy.util.ConfigSlurper["classLoader"]->groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader["resourceLoader"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:26) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:491) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:412) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:27) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:491) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:412) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:27) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:128) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1902) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

I have attempted to disable the fail on empty beans option for Jackson as indicated in the stacktrace without success. I tried specifying the spring.jackson.serialization.fail_on_empty_beans property to false as suggested at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper but this didn't work and I saw the same stacktrace.

How do I either disable the fail on empty beans option or not serialize closures to the /env endpoint of Spring Boot Actuator?

Comment: I get the same error but with a jaxrs Form it is super wierd. This happens on request invokation. com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class javax.ws.rs.core.Form and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )